# Cadenas de conexión desde .Net a Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, odac

Tengo una duda, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre estas dos cadenas de conexión?

```
 conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;OLE DB Services=3;User Id=xxx;Password=yyy;Data Source=zzzz")
 conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=ORAOLEDB.ORACLE;OLE DB Services=3;User Id=xxx;Password=yyy;Data Source=zzzz")
```

Unas me funcionan en unos equipos y la segunda cadena en otros, en otros equipos funcionan las dos y en otros equipos ninguna, imagino que es por el `ODAC` (version, release, arquitectura (x86 o x64) u otros factores).

Entonces creo que puedo resumir en dos preguntas:

1. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre ambos?
2. ¿Para utilizar cada una de ellas qué debo tener instalado?

> Nota. Me di cuenta que el `ODAC` 11 tiene dos Ole DB (Oracle Provider for Ole DB y Oracle objects for Ole) y el `ODAC` 12 tiene solamente uno (Oracle Provider for Ole DB)

Answer (score 2):

Paso a intentar solventar tu duda:

1. MSDAORA: Es el [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms675851(v=vs.85).aspx). Es una implementación del adaptador para OLE DB realizado por Microsoft, que si lees atentamente la documentación, es una característica que está obsoleta y que se recomienda usar el proveedor de OLE DB implementado por Oracle.
2. ORAOLEDB.ORACLE: Es el proveedor de OLE DB de Oracle. En este enlace [Introduction to Oracle Provider for OLE DB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a95498/intro.htm) puedes ver los requisitos necesarios para su instalación